# community 360 component on chat transcript

Tags: community, service-cloud-console, community-cloud

I would like to have community 360 component on chat transcript lightning page. Is that possible? If not is there any special license that Salesforce provides for doing so?

Comment: Do you mean [Customer 360](https://www.salesforce.com/solutions/customer-360/)?

Comment: No.. I mean.. Community 360 - The component useful for service reps to have a view on community history (articles viiewed, cases raised etc..) for a community user